# Using BitBucket's API to fork a repository

Tags: api, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

There's any way to fork a repository using BB's API?

From what I've read on the API's docs, there isn't any explicit one: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Repositories

My idea is to create a new repo and point that it's a fork of another one, so I can create pull requests later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the API to fork a repository, either using Basic authorization or OAuth.

The method to fork a repository:

Using a authorized POST-request with required post data "name".
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}/fork/

Full documentation with optional parameters here:
http://restbrowser.bitbucket.org/

Comment: Is this new? I'm pretty sure it wasn't there before.

Comment: I don't know @dmmd. It is in version 1.0 of the API but I don't know when they implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

So..

Tried to contact support via twitter and comments on the API page. Didn't get an answer...

And it seems that they really don't have a method to create forks.

My solution:

- Created a cURL interface to interact with BitBucket's website, and from there I could fork and create pull requests

If you have a better solution for that, or if they actually have the method on the API, please fell free to drop your answer here.

Follow up: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4376/api-method-to-fork-a-repository

Answer (score 2):

.

you can to fork the repositories using Bitbucket API without need to username and password, only using bitbucket application.

There is [HERE](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/repository+Resource+1.0#repositoryResource1.0-POSTanewfork) the doc's for POST a new fork.

Also you need to base knowledge of OAuth, following links are helpful .

1. [OAuth on Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/OAuth+on+Bitbucket)
2. [Use the Bitbucket REST APIs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs)
3. [Bitbucket API version 1](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Version+1)
4. [Bitbucket API version 2](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Version+2)
5. [Bitbucket REST API Browser](http://restbrowser.bitbucket.org/)

If you are a wordpress developer, [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-bucket/) can be helpful for you.

.

[image: code.png]

Comment: Please add some description here.

Answer (score 0):

2022 TLDR;

Bitbucket cloud 2.0 API with minimal required fields ([API Ref](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-forks-post)) as far as I can tell:

```
POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/forks

{
  "is_private": true,
  "scm": "git",
  "name": {new_workspace},
  "workspace":{
      "slug":{new_reposlug}
  }
}
```

For example, imagine you have repo `foo` in workspace `sandbox`.  And you want to make a fork `foo-fork` in the same workspace.

```
POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/sandbox/foo/forks

{
  "is_private": true,
  "scm": "git",
  "name": "foo-fork",
  "workspace":{
      "slug":"sandbox"
  }
}
```

The response is quite large and will show al the other optional request fields